# Expected value of a random variable whose distribution depends on another random variable

Tags: probability

I have two random variables $T_1\sim U(0,1)$ and $T_2 \sim U(T_1,1)$. How do you calculate the expected value of $T_2$? Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{E}[T_2]=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}[T_2|T_1]\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac {1+T_1} 2\right]=\frac {1+\frac 1 2} 2=\frac 3 4$.

Comment: Oh yeah, law of total probability.... Thank you.